# Using try_files and rewrite within an NGINX location block, with a default front-controller file

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am migrating from an old framework to a new framework in php. The old framework had a landing page for every URL, such as:

1. `test.com/page1` would be routed to `public_directory/page1.php`
2. `test.com/another_page` would be routed to `public_directory/another_page.php`
3. etc.

The following block was used for these requests:

```
location / { 
    limit_req zone=globallimit burst=20 nodelay;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php; 
}

location @php {         
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)$ $1.php last;
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)/(.*)$ $1.php?q=$2 last;
}
```

The new framework uses a front controller, and every request needs to be directed to `public_directory/front_controller.php`. As we migrate we are removing the old landing files, which is how we can identify which pages use the new framework.

What I thought would work is the following, after the `@php` block, adding a default argument to `front_controller.php`:

```
location / { 
    limit_req zone=globallimit burst=20 nodelay;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php /front_controller.php?$arg; 
}

location @php {         
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)$ $1.php last;
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)/(.*)$ $1.php?q=$2 last;
}
```

If the @php rewrite block doesn't match a file, then it should default to `/front_controller.php?arg`; however, what I am finding is that now @php is ignored and `nginx` is instead going directly to front_controller.php. Where am I going wrong, why is the @php rewrite now being ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try_files` directive expect a list of files followed by the URI / named location / HTTP error code that will be used if none of the files in a list exists. Assuming your site root directory is `/home/user/www` and your request is `http://example.com/some/path` this configuration check the existence of following files/directories:

1. `/home/user/www/some/path` file, if the file is found it's contents will be returned in response body.
2. `/home/user/www/some/path/` directory, if this directory exists, it will be checked for all possible index files defined with the `index` directive, first found file will be used. If no index files found in this directory, nginx returns directory contents if you have `autoindex on;` or HTTP 403 Forbidden otherwise.
3. `/home/user/www@php` file. Obviously, this file would not be found.

If none of these checks succeed, nginx will follow an URI (or named location) defined as the last argument (`/front_controller.php?$arg` in this case).

What you can do is to try something like

```
location ~ ^(/[^/]+)$ {
    try_files $1.php /front_controller.php?$arg;
}
location ~ ^(?<script>/[^/]+)/(?<param>.*)$ {
    rewrite ^ $script?q=$param last;
}
```

However I do not understand where `$arg` variable should come from. Maybe you mean `$is_args$args`?

### Update

I was wrong, you can check the existence of php script with `try_files` directive, but this script would not be passed to your php handler location block. Your task intrigued me, and finally I got something working:

```
# backup original args
set $original_args $args;
if ($uri ~ "^(/[^/]+)(?:/(.*))?$") {
    set $script $1.php;
    set $param $2;
}
if ($param) {
    set $args "q=$param";
}
location / { 
    limit_req zone=globallimit burst=20 nodelay;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php; 
}
location @php {
    if ( !-f $document_root$script ) {
        # old landing php file is absent, restore original args and rewrite URI to /front_controller.php
        set $args $original_args;
        set $script /front_controller.php;
    }
    rewrite ^ $script last;
}
```

### Update 2 @ 2022.06.16

When I occasionally come upon some of my old answers, they are really makes me cry sometimes. Here is how I'd solve this now, after a few years of nginx experience:

```
set $original_args $is_args$args;
location / { 
    limit_req zone=globallimit burst=20 nodelay;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php; 
}
location @php {         
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)$ $1.php last;
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)/(.*)$ $1.php?q=$2 last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /front_controller.php$original_args;
    ... rest of the original PHP handler here
}
```

Comment: Okay I understand why the @php fails in this instance in that case. Would it not make more sense in that case to use the original command as shown: `try_files $uri $uri/ @php;` and add a final rewrite to the `@php` block that directs all requests to front_controller.php, such as: `rewrite ^(...)$ /front_controller.php$is_args$args?;`?

Comment: This final rewrite rule would never be reached, one of the first two rewrite rules will be triggered for any request except `/`. You need to check the existence if old landing php file, and the `try_files` directive seems to me the best way to do it. But my example wouldn't work also, I'm thinking on how to rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks! That's quite the nginx configuration requirements, I didn't expect this to be so challenging. I'm hesitant to use if with nginx so at this point I am thinking directing all requests to the front controller and having it route to an old landing file if the file exists might be the best bet, then just using a simple try_files string within the nginx config

Comment: It's completely up to you, but just FYI these `if` constructions are completely safe because no other directives except those from [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) are used inside them, and no other directives except those from `ngx_http_rewrite_module` are used in the location blocks where `if` is used. So no configuration blocks duplication or other negative effects could occur. If you interested, internal implementation of `ngx_http_rewrite_module` described [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#internals).

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'll take a look